# Call order of constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    
struct A{
  A() {cout << "A" << endl;}
  A(int a) {cout << "A+" << endl;}
};

struct B : virtual A{
  B() : A(1) {cout << "B" << endl;}
};
struct C : virtual A{
  C() : A(1) {cout << "C" << endl;}
};
struct D : virtual A{
  D() : A() {cout << "D" << endl;}
};
struct E : B, virtual C, D{
  E(){cout << "E" << endl;}
};
struct F : D, virtual C{
  F(){cout << "F" << endl;}
};
struct G : E, F{
  G() {cout << "G" << endl;}
};

int main(){
  G g;
  return 0;
}
```

Program prints:

```
A
C
B
D
E
D
F
G
```

I would like to know what rules should I use to determine in what order constructors get called. Thanks.

Comment: The virtual bases are constructed by the most derived class before any other bases.

Comment: To elaborate on @KerrekSB's comment and the fact that `A+` isn't printed, note that changing `D` to call `A(1)` has the same behaviour, then have a look at [this one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c9d7a9bf6a0b0aa). Now all three call `A()`, but `G` calls `A(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the rules given in the C++ standard:

> `[C++11: 12.6.2/10]:` In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>
> - **First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of appearance of the base classes in the derived class *base-specifier-list*.**
> - **Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).**
> - Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
> - Finally, the *compound-statement* of the constructor body is executed.
>
> *[ Note:* The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of initialization. *—end note ]*

Answer (score 1):

Virtual base subobjects are constructed first, by the most-derived class, before any other bases. This is the only way that makes sense, since the relation of the virtual bases to tbe most-derived object is not known until object construction, at runtime (hence "virtual"). All intermediate initializers for virtual bases are ignored.

So, what are your virtual bases? `G` derives from `E` and `F`. `E` derives virtually from `C`, which in turn derives virtually from `A`, so `A`, `C` are first. Next, `F` doesn't add any further virtual bases. Next, `E` has non-virtual bases `B` and `D`, in that order, which are constructed next, and then `E` is complete. Then comes `F`'s non-virtual base `D`, and `F` is complete. Finally, `G` is complete.

All in all, it's virtual bases `A`, `C`, then non-virtual bases `B`, `D`, `E` and `D`, `F`, and then `G` itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the order of constructor calls from this quote of the C++ Standard and try to trap it yourself

> 10 In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
>   following order: — First, and only for the constructor of the most
>   derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order
>   they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed
>   acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of
>   appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list. — Then, direct base classes are initialized in
>   declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
>   (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers). — Then, non-static
>   data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the
>   class definition (again regardless of the order of the
>   mem-initializers). — Finally, the compound-statement of the
>   constructor body is executed. [ Note: The declaration order is
>   mandated to ensure that base and member subobjects are destroyed in
>   the reverse order of initialization. —end note ]