# multi level inheritance constructor execution

Tags: c++

```
class A {
public:
    A(int) {
        cout << "Base class" << endl;
    }
};

class B : virtual public A {
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
};

class C : public B {
public:
    C()
        : A(1) {
        cout << "C class" << endl;
    }

    virtual void do_something() {
    }
};
```

Compiler Error: when object for C is created, compiler is resulting error like

> error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A()’

why compiler expects default constructor of class A?

Comment: Thank the lord for clang-format.

Comment: Read the ISOCPP FAQ section on these concepts http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance & http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/basics-of-inheritance

Comment: [Which compiler?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0d980808c205ea9)

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no explicit initialization for the `B` part of `C` in `C::C()`, the compiler uses the default constructor of `B` to do that.

```
C()
    : A(1) {
    cout << "C class" << endl;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
C()
    : B(), A(1) {
    cout << "C class" << endl;
}
```

The default constructor of `B` tries to initialize the `A` part by using the default constructor of `A`, which does not exist. That's the compiler error message.

You can fix it by one of the following methods:

1. Provide a default constructor for `A`.
2. Provide a default constructor for `B` in which use `A(int)` to initialize the `A` part of `B`.

**Update**

Why does the compiler want to want `A::A()` in `B::B()`? Because it does not know that, at run time, an instance of `C` will be constructed.

Take the following scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
   public:
      A(int)
      {
         cout << "Came to A(int)" << endl;
      }
};

class B : virtual public A
{
   public:
      virtual void do_something(){};
};

int main()
{
   B b;
}
```

It's clear why `B::B()` needs to call `A::A(int)` or expect an `A::A()`. Since the compiler cannot, apriori, figure out whether `B` is the most derived class, it has to make sure that there is a way to initialize `A` from `B`, if necessary.

Comment: The most derived class is responsible for the `A` subobject's initialization since it's inherited virtually.

Comment: Found the quotation (§10.1 [class.mi]/4): *For each distinct base class that is
specified virtual, the most derived object shall contain a single base class subobject of that type*

Comment: @chris, I agree with what you are saying. That still leaves the question: How is `B` initialized? That's where the OP's code is getting the compiler error.

Comment: Well, sure, `B`'s default constructor is called, but I don't think that should call `A`'s.

Comment: Oh, [here we go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21034121/962089). This is what I was looking for and couldn't find for some reason. `B()` should definitely not call `A()`.

Comment: Hi Sahu, if i provide default constructor for A like A(){cout<<" class A default constructor"<<endl}. if i execute the program, the compiler error is not received but output is not printing the statemet whatever I added for class A default constructor.

Comment: @chris, The compiler expects a `A::A()` while creating `B::B()` even though `A` is a virtual base class. See http://ideone.com/732FQY. Maybe it's a bug in g++.

Comment: @user3665615, I see exactly what you saw. At run time, `B::B()` does not call `A::A()` but the compiler seems to want it.

Answer (score 0):

`B` has no default constructor.

`B` has no user-defined default constructor, and the compiler-provided default constructor would be ill-formed, because it would have to use `A` default constructor, and `A` has none.

Even though `B` default constructor should not call `A` constructor when `B` is used as a base class, you still need a valid default constructor for `B` if you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a breakdown of the problem, in C++11:

- Since there is no user-declared constructor for `B`, a constructor with no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted.  However, since there is no default constructor for `A`, this constructor is *defined as deleted*. Ref `[class.ctor]#5`. (This actually means that a `B` can never be created because it has no non-deleted constructors).
- `C`'s constructor does not mention `B` in its initializer list, therefore the `B` subobject is default-initialized. Ref `[class.base.init]#8`
- Default initialization of an object with no accessible default constructor means the program is ill-formed. Ref `[dcl.init]#6`

There is a clause in `[class.base.init]#8` that a base class does not require a constructor *if it is a virtual base class of an abstract class*. However that is not the case here. `A` is such a class, but `B` is not.

Summary - there is no valid constructor for the `B` subobject of the `C`.